# want to customise django cms forms using custom styling

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-cms, divio

I'm following this tutorial (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangocms-forms/) to create custom forms with django-forms in this tutorial, Essentially, I want to know how to define my own "FORM TEMPLATE" for this plugin.I want to include my own styling and post requests too.
 Thank you

Comment: you just need to print the form `{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}` in any template that you wish and also you can apply your stylings in the same template.

Comment: I want to create simple lead form with name, email and mobile field and call ajax to save in the database.I am novice to django so can anyone guide how can I achieve this?